# Is Node.js suitable for my project given how I'm using it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm about to start writing an application and I want to include newer technologies to improve my knowledge and gain a skill set.

I'm using mysql to store user data (no choice), Angular.js to display/template content on the dom, and I wanted to use node.js to return results from the database in json format to be used by Angular.js.

My assumption was I could use node.js (along with the node-mysql module and maybe express)to accomplish my database queries that feed into my Angular.js templates.

Additionally, the application will live on a different server than the database itself and may reside in a mobile framework.

Am I way off base when it come to how to use node.js? Am I just using the wrong tool? Am I on the right track?

Any help, explanation, and points in the right direction would be great. Most of the info I've seen are copy/paste from the node.js site/wiki and don't really answer my question.

Comment: you dont have a option? Why not use EJS and a Nosql data-base?

Comment: The host I'm using to store the database doesn't give an nosql option. I want to use MongoDB but that's only for dedicated servers and I'm on a shared server. To be clear, this will be for demo purposes. If I get the chance to go further I'd like to add more new tech like a nosql DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is largely an opinion-based question and likely to be closed, but you're not way off base.  What you want to do is absolutely (and commonly) done using Node.js.

As a complete aside, you might like to check out Platform-as-a-Service providers such as Heroku.com and Nodejitsu.com; both offer great and easy Node.js hosting and addons (such as NoSQL and RDBMS data stores) which have free tiers.

For that matter, MongoLab and MongoHQ both offer free tiers independent of Heroku, which you could use from your MySQL-only hosting provider if you like.

Comment: I understand this isn't the best use of SO. I'll remove the question, if needed. Just couldn't find a straight answer. Thanks for the info on the hosting. If this project picks up I'll have to look for different hosting for sure. I'm reviewing the requirements. If node.js isn't required I may just run some php on the server and use JS to run ajax requests for now.

Comment: I don't mind, I definitely understand that feeling when you first look at a technology of "does this fit my problem".  My answer is that yes it's definitely possible to do with Node, and many folks have used the architecture you proposed. I've built several applications where Express ends up being a REST API server, and Angular does all the UI work, talking in pure JSON back to Express.  And having your DB on a different server is a good practice when you go 'production' anyway.